# Recreate apple pay circle wave in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

It is possible to recreate this circle of waves around a symbol, my knowledge is basic, it is drawing Circle but not placing them around something circular. The other point is how to make the gradient expand across all the circles as if they were one.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is drawing Circle but not placing them around something circular

It *is* circular. If you observe carefully, you'll see there are 4 "bands" of circles of different sizes. The polar angles of the 2nd and 4th bands are shifted a little bit, so the bands don't look "aligned". But you can see that the 2nd and 4th bands align with each other, and the 1st and 3rd bands align with each other.

You can represent this with such a struct:

```
struct CircularBand {
    let count: Int
    let radius: CGFloat
    let circleRadius: CGFloat
    let offset: Angle
}
```

> how to make the gradient expand across all the circles as if they were one.

For this, you can just create a single `Path` that consists of all the circles you want to draw, instead of filling each circle individually.

Here is an example with some hardcoded numbers:

```
var pathWithCircles: Path {
    let bands = [
        CircularBand(count: 24, radius: 100, circleRadius: 4, offset: .zero),
        CircularBand(count: 24, radius: 110, circleRadius: 5, offset: .degrees(360 / 24 / 2)),
        CircularBand(count: 24, radius: 120, circleRadius: 6, offset: .zero),
        CircularBand(count: 24, radius: 130, circleRadius: 6.5, offset: .degrees(360 / 24 / 2)),
    ]
    return Path { p in
        for band in bands {
            let circle = Path(ellipseIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: -band.radius, width: band.circleRadius * 2, height: band.circleRadius * 2))
            for i in 0..<band.count {
                p.addPath(circle, transform:
                        .init(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2 / CGFloat(band.count) * CGFloat(i) + band.offset.radians)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I'm assuming the centre of the circle is (0, 0). When you draw this on a `Canvas`, you can translate the graphics context so that (0, 0) is the centre of the canvas.

```
Canvas { c, size in
    c.translateBy(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
    c.fill(pathWithCircles, with: .conicGradient(.init(colors: [.red, .green, .blue, .red]), center: .zero))
}
```

Output:

[image]